# How to return a soap fault with content from an orchestration?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations, biztalk-wcf

In an orchestration (BizTalk 2010), we receive an xml message, validate the message against a schema, and perform schematron (content) validation as well.  Our orchestration is exposed via a WCF service.  Our validation routines are able to capture all validation errors, which we want to return via a soap fault containing all the validation errors.  Additionally, we want the orchestration to complete normally, even in the case of validation errors (no suspended messages).    How can we go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use normal soap fault then then all you need to do is add soap fault message part to the receive port. In your orchestration do the validation and if it fails then construct a soap fault message and send that message instead of the normal result.

You will probably need to do the above within a scope so that you can handle exceptions and let the orchestration terminate gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

See [Using SOAP Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253855%28v=bts.10%29.aspx), specifically, SOAP Headers with Published Web Services.